# ROS Answers SE migration: CAD Models

Tags: ros, household-objects-database, roboearth, cad, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working on CAD Models ( 3D Models ) ,,,
I want some package to help my robot " with a kinect on it " to make a matching between CAD Model and point Cloud of a specific object ,so it can detect and recognize the object with high accuracy and from the whole four sides.
I'm using ROS fruete and Ubuntu 11.10.
I have created object's point cloud ( object model ) using RoboEarth Stack , What is the suitable database of 3D models to use ?..can I use an external Database uploaded on the web ! or  must use household_objects_database ?.. and which package can be used for this matching ??

After searching .. I found that I can use household_objects_database with tabletop_objects_detector or use blort_ros with TOD database , but I have faced some problems with them .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56312/cad-models/) by [RiskTeam](https://answers.ros.org/users/3338/riskteam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2013-02-26

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To do these kind of things the library you want to use is PCL of which there is a ROS version too.

It can handle most of the phases of 3D object recognition.

As for using a remote DB I'd vouch against it due to latency: such models tend to be quite large.

---

Originally posted by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) with karma: 859 on 2013-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0